# how to find a[i]th element in array b

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to show the word located at a(i)th index in array day, time, srcdes
but the output is coming twisted.I am getting the output i expected but between two array elements there are 3 non required elements are generated eg

**output**

```
Sunday-9-Dombivli-DombivliMonday-10-Thane-ThaneWednesday-12-Vikhroli-VikhroliSunday-9-Dombivli-Dombivli
```

here "-9-Dombivli-DombivliMonday" is not required. After sunday directly 10 should be generated eg.

**Expected output**

```
Sunday-10-vikhroli-dombivli
```

**code**

```
var days = 
 ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];  
var time = ["9", "10","11","12","1","2","3"];  
var srcdes = ["Dombivli", "Thane","Mulund","Vikhroli","Ghatkopar","Sion","Dadar"];  
var a = [0,2,3,0]
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
 z = a[i]
document.write(days[z]+"-"+time[z] +"-" + srcdes[z] +"-"+ srcdes[z] )
 }
```

what am i doing wrong? thank you for your suggestions

Comment: Why you need for loop? It can be done without a loop [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jptv0d5n/4/)

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve, your question isn't very clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]; 
var time = ["9", "10","11","12","1","2","3"]; 
var srcdes = ["Dombivli","Thane","Mulund","Vikhroli","Ghatkopar","Sion","Dadar"]; 
var a = [0,2,3,0]
document.write(days[a[0]]+"-"+time[a[1]] +"-" + srcdes[a[2]] +"-"+ srcdes[a[3]] )
```

There is no need for the loop,